# Remove elements from priority queue in golang

Tags: go, heap, priority-queue

I take the full realization of priority queue from [golang docs](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__priorityQueue). I'm interesting in removing several elements at once like `heap.Remove(&queue, index1, index2, ...)`.

Now it can be done in the straightforward way:

```
for _, event := range events {
    heap.Remove(&queue, event.getIndex())
}
```

But this method has an overhead because every call to `heap.Remove` reorganizes tree. It seems  more efficient if we can remove all unnecessary elements firstly and only then reorganize tree.

How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the underlying data structure of your heap is a slice, you can remove the elements directly from the slice and re-initialize the heap again after.

Starting from your example:

```
for _, event := range events {
    i := event.GetIndex()
    queue[i], queue[len(queue)-1] = queue[len(queue)-1], queue[i]
    queue = queue[:len(queue)-1]
}
heap.Init(&queue)
```

And a working example: https://play.golang.org/p/-KMEilCm3t9

```
func main() {
    h := IntHeap{1, 5, 2, 9, 8, 3, 7}

    toRemove := 8
    for i := 0; i < len(h); i++ {
        n := h[i]
        if n == toRemove {
            h[i], h[len(h)-1] = h[len(h)-1], h[i]
            h = h[:len(h)-1]
            i--
        }
    }

    heap.Init(&h)
    fmt.Println(h)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question we first need to understand what a heap is.  Heaps are a data structure that allow us to find the largest or smallest value depending on whether it is a Min Heap or a Max Heap.  To do this quickly, the computer maintains a tree, this image sums it up quite well.  This is a max heap:

[image: Max-heap diagram, nine nodes]

Of course computer's memory aren't laid out in trees, they are laid out linearly.  In fact, go stores heaps in slices, which means that you can iterate through the slice and remove elements like you'd normally do, for example:

```
  for i:=0; i<len(heap); i++ {  
    for _, element := heap {
      if element == to_remove {
        heap = append(heap[:i], heap[i+1:])
        i--
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: removing elements from the heap slice, even while maintaining order, can break the heap invariants. Since you need to  re-heapify the slice anyway, it's much faster to not maintain slice order.

Comment: Good point, the main point for me here is to demonstrate that the heap is interanaly a slice so looking for a way to remove multiple elements from a heap at one time might mean that you should reconsider the data structure being used.